# Woocommerce checkout page has unconfigurable fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I am stuck with trying to configure my website's checkout fields in woo commerce.It comes prefilled with values and doesnt get removed even after purging the cache.
https://shinujohn.com/checkout/ ...set as with the default shortcode
[image]

The country has 2 field boxes now...one is clickable drop down.
Server side caching is disabled.

The theme I'm using is Kallyas

I  Have tried:-

1. Field editor : It does not even show the field ..say company name.and adding a new field is not reflected here.even if i add it to the billing or  checkout fields
   [image]
2. Adding code to functions.php

/*returning woo commerce field as blank*/

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_get_value','__return_empty_string', 1, 1);
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields' , 'custom_override_billing_fields' );

or

    function custom_override_billing_fields( $fields ) {
      unset($fields['billing_postcode']);
      unset($fields['billing_state']);
      unset($fields['billing_country']);
      unset($fields['billing_address_1']);
      return $fields;
    }
```

neither work
3. issue persists with multiple browsers and unlogged users in different machines..
4. Within the theme's page editor... i can of course change front end ...but it doesnt reflect it after publishing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you to use any extra plugin to edit the Woocommerce checkout fields. Here is the simple solution that you can easily customize the Woocommerce checkout fields.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_billing_fields', 5);

function custom_override_billing_fields( $fields ) {
     unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
     unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
     unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
     unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']);
     return $fields;
}
```

May this code helps you.

Comment: Thank you Suresh
I added this code snippet but the issue persists.
purged the cache too

Comment: @ShinuJohn Please print the `$fields` array inside the `custom_override_billing_fields` function and remove the required fields from the array. May this helps you